# How to assign RouteWayPoint string to MapPushPin.text?

Tags: c#, devexpress, bing-maps

I have a list of routewaypoints as below, I need to name them with letters, and I want to show the assigned letters on Mappushpins. When I declare Mappushpins under LayersItemGenerating , it names them alphabetically in route order. I want the same letters as in the list. How can I do that?And secondly, is there a way to show the order in textbox? Like Point 1:A, Point 2:F, Point 3:E, Point 4:B etc.

```
public void Optimise()
{
    List<RouteWaypoint> Nodeslist = new List<RouteWaypoint>();
    char NodeCode = 'A';

        Nodeslist.Add(new RouteWaypoint("{0}" + NodeCode.ToString(), new DevExpress.XtraMap.GeoPoint(38.481713, 27.088842)));
        Nodeslist.Add(new RouteWaypoint("{0}" + NodeCode++.ToString(), new DevExpress.XtraMap.GeoPoint(38.477967, 27.095194)));
        Nodeslist.Add(new RouteWaypoint("{0}" + NodeCode++.ToString(), new DevExpress.XtraMap.GeoPoint(38.468979, 27.109935)));
        Nodeslist.Add(new RouteWaypoint("{0}" + NodeCode++.ToString(), new DevExpress.XtraMap.GeoPoint(38.473381, 27.112424)));
        Nodeslist.Add(new RouteWaypoint("{0}" + NodeCode++.ToString(), new DevExpress.XtraMap.GeoPoint(38.459930, 27.090800)));
        Nodeslist.Add(new RouteWaypoint("{0}" + NodeCode++.ToString(), new DevExpress.XtraMap.GeoPoint(38.469622, 27.075265)));
        Nodeslist.Add(new RouteWaypoint("{0}" + NodeCode++.ToString(), new DevExpress.XtraMap.GeoPoint(38.455494, 27.119999)));
        Nodeslist.Add(new RouteWaypoint("{0}" + NodeCode++.ToString(), new DevExpress.XtraMap.GeoPoint(38.451671, 27.114656)));
        Nodeslist.Add(new RouteWaypoint("{0}" + NodeCode++.ToString(), new DevExpress.XtraMap.GeoPoint(38.469483, 27.134998)));
        Nodeslist.Add(new RouteWaypoint("{0}" + NodeCode++.ToString(), new DevExpress.XtraMap.GeoPoint(38.468074, 27.085409)));

        RouteProvider.CalculateRoute(Nodeslist);
}
void RouteProvider_LayerItemsGenerating(object sender, LayerItemsGeneratingEventArgs e)
{            
        char NodePinMarker= 'A';
        foreach (MapItem item in e.Items)
        {
            MapPushpin NodePin = item as MapPushpin;
            if(NodePin != null)
            {
                NodePin.Text = NodePinMarker++.ToString();            
            }

        }
}
```

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @rbrundritt no it's not. I don't know where to declare the mappushpins..

Answer (score 0):

Add a VectorLayer to the map and then add the pushpins to that layer.
https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/clsDevExpressXpfMapMapPushpintopic

Comment: I don't have a problem on adding the pushpins to the map.. My problem is I can't set the text of the pushpin as the same as the descriptions of Routewaypoints.

Comment: According to the documentation for devexpress, there is a Text property that should work. Maybe try creating a string variable firs then assigning it to the Text property.

Comment: I already have the values as strings and I can write texts on pushpins I only can't do them in the same order as routewaypoints.